# Using apply with Spatial*DataFrame

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following SpatialPointsDataFrame

```
library(sp)
exdf <- data.frame(cbind(1:10, 41:50, 101:110))
names(exdf) <- c("id", "x", "y")
coordinates(exdf) <- c("x", "y")
```

I can run the following `apply`

```
apply(exdf@data, 1, function(x) { 
                      cat(coordinates(exdf[exdf$id == x["id"],]), "\n") 
                                })
```

However it seems ridiculous to select from the same data frame within the function. I'm already iterating through it.

Note that, in my actual use, I need to send *both* the data frame row and the coordinates to another function, so `apply`ing only on the `exdf@coords` is not an option.

Question 1: Is there a way to do this without `exdf[exdf$id == x["id"],]` part?

Question 2: If not, is there a package that I can use instead of `sp` for such tasks. I need `sp` for its `over` function primarily, and checked also `spatstat` and decided `sp` is simpler to use. However using a "data frame" that's not actually a `data.frame` annoys me.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you actually want to do? What is this other function called?

Comment: @SimonO101: one of the columns is a vector. each row has a time series like data. it compares this row with the rows in a dataset, given a rectangular area of candidates. the rectangular area changes for each query row, it creates a rectangular polygon from query row's coordinates, then makes an overlay on dataset rows to get candidates. i can write all these manually but i would like to use elegant existing solutions if they are available.

Comment: I edited my answer, but must admit you haven't quite clarified what your desired end result is and what constraints apply.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily transform your SpatialPointsDataFrame into a regular `data.frame` and then proceed from there:

```
> df <- as.data.frame(exdf)
> df
   id  x   y
1   1 41 101  
2   2 42 102
3   3 43 103
4   4 44 104
5   5 45 105
6   6 46 106
7   7 47 107
8   8 48 108
9   9 49 109
10 10 50 110
> paste(df$x, df$y, sep=' ')
 [1] "41 101" "42 102" "43 103" "44 104" "45 105" "46 106" "47 107" "48 108" "49 109" "50 110"
```

**Edit:** From the comment, the OP would like to achieve the result in simpler ways but without converting the Spatial*DataFrame into a data.frame. The same result as in his example can be achieved with the following code, but it needs to be changed if additional columns would also be printed/concatenated/processed:

```
cat(paste(exdf@coords[,1], exdf@coords[,2]), sep='\n')
```

Comment: I agree this is more elegant but does it differ from, say, `lapply(seq(to=nrow(exdf), function(i) { el <- exdf[i,] })` performance wise? I have a large data frame and I don't like to convert back and forth between its spatial equivalent. I could also keep extra columns for `x` and `y` , but then, I could simply write a function that finds rows within a rectangle. :)

Comment: Well, it's useful to be clear in your problem statement. You didn't say you were concerned about performance -- it sounded your interest was in readability. Also, optimising performance or memory for a dataset of 10 points would have been insane - if size of your dataset is relevant, it's good to say so in the question. I'll give it some more thought.